# How to create a multi-line options menu item (SubMenu)

Tags: android, android-layout, menuitem

I have a really long title for MenuItem (Added as a SubMenu).
When added to Action-bar the menu item spills over the screen.
Even adding a "\n" in the title does not help.
Is there a way to make the title appear in two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom layout for this type of menu. Here is an approach [Android Action bar custom dropdown view on item click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868774/android-action-bar-custom-dropdown-view-on-item-click).

Comment: and what is Dropdown item there?