# Navigation View Multiline Text

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, multiline

I have an app with a Navigation View for my DrawerLayout. I add programmatically items in the menu because I receive the information over the network. But sometimes, an item name can be very long and is just cut off with even having the ellipsize icon "..."

Does someone have an idea on how to have multiline for my menu items?

Thanks

Answer (score 23):

Override *design_navigation_menu_item.xml* from the Android Support Design Library and modify the things you need (set `android:ellipsize="end"` and `android:maxLines="2"`)

Your *res/layout/design_navigation_menu_item.xml* should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/design_menu_item_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/design_navigation_icon_padding"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2" />
    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/design_menu_item_action_area_stub"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/design_menu_item_action_area"
        android:layout="@layout/design_menu_item_action_area"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</merge>
```

**However**, you should just ellipsize the text to properly follow the Material Design guidelines.

You have not to override anything to just ellipsize the text:

- Add a new style to the *styles.xml*
- Set the new style to the `NavigationView`

*res / values / styles.xml*

```
<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
</style>
```

*res / layout / activity_main.xml*

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    app:theme="@style/TextAppearance" />
```

Comment: Nice.. after lot of wasting time. Got solution. Thanks

Comment: great answer :)

Comment: Thank you. Using the following style I managed to show 2 lines without override anything: 

    <style name="TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:lines">2</item>
    </style>

Comment: This solution used to work well. But now, the `design_navigation_menu_item.xml` file is being restored back to its original version when I build the app. Does anyone have a workaround? (BTW, I have already tried building the app offline, in vain)

Comment: how to implement the same for options menu (system popup items on the right of toolbar)?

Answer (score 12):

Just add `app:itemMaxLines="2"` attribute on the **NavigationView** tag like this:

```
<com.google.android.mayerial.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
app:itemMaxLines="2" />
```

**NOTE:** Material dependency is--

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material.material:1.0.0'
```

Comment: ATTENTION: the correct version is `1.1.0`, there is no such attr or method in `1.0.0` material lib

Answer (score 4):

Add a style to your NavigationDrawer and then include 2 lines in the style.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@drawable/estilo"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

<style name="NavigationDrawerStyle">
    <item name="android:lines">2</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491243/how-to-create-a-multi-line-options-menu-item-submenu). Default android slide menu is not very flexible, most likely you will have to create your custom view.
I really [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) tutorial from AndroidHive.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried and tried, There was no progress with `Menu`, I don't say it was impossible but I couldn't find a way to break `MenuItem` lines.

But if you don't insist on using `Menu` I suggest you to use a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` in your layout like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_draw_header">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

As you can see there is no special thing to explain, no menu, just a `RecyclerView`, `layout_marginTop` value is same as header height, I'm sure you know the rest of the story (How to fire up `RecyclerView`), This approach gives more flexibility to `NavigationView` menu items (actually `RecyclerView` items).
 If my answer is not clear enough to you let me know.

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't change that.

Check out the material design guideline: https://material.io/design/components/navigation-drawer.html#anatomy

Comment: Personally, in certain cases, I believe that breaking the Material design guidelines doesn't necessarily mean Bad UI design. This was one such case (for my implementation)

Comment: in support of what @Kathir said, there's a reason they're called "guidelines" and not "rules".  Basically:  "it's your app, make it your own.  Here's some helpful guidelines to assist you with design.  Feel free to use them... or not"

Answer (score -1):

Add a style in your NavigationDrawer that declares the number of lines as 'two', like so:

```
 <style name="NavigationDrawerStyle">
        <item name="android:lines">2</item>
    </style>
```

and in your view:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/estilo"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```