# How to set multiline for navigationdrawer menu items?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How to set multiline for menu items in navigationdrawer (if item's text doesn't fit to navigationdrawer width?

Comment: Use this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729974/navigation-view-multiline-text

Comment: check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43947132/5836953

Answer (score 11):

Combining answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40575681/10824768 with comments found an easy solution

> - Add a new style to the styles.xml
> - Set the new style to the    NavigationView
>
> res / values / styles.xml
>
> ```
> <style name="TextAppearance">
>     <item name="android:lines">2</item>
> </style>
> ```
>
> res / layout / activity_main.xml
>
> ```
> <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>     android:id="@+id/nav_view"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:layout_gravity="start"
>     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>     app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
>     app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
>     app:theme="@style/TextAppearance" />
> ```

Comment: Done It saves my time ! yeah @karakuku

Comment: i tried several other solutions including this one with different attributes, but this is the only one that works for me

Answer (score 10):

Right now it can be done much easier - just use `app:itemMaxLines="2"`

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
  android:id="@+id/nav_side_view"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="start"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
  app:headerLayout="@layout/view_nav_header"
  app:itemMaxLines="2"
  app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />
```

Comment: It works but remember to use `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0` and `compileSdkVersion` 29.