# How to handle long text on action bar sub menus and on PopupMenu?

Tags: android, text, android-actionbar, multiline, popupmenu

### Background

I have [**an app**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager) that shows a list of apps, and has an actionBar. one of the actionBar items has a sub menu that show the various ways to sort the list that is shown on the screen.

### The problem

I'm trying to make the app being translated to Greek, and it turns out that some textual UI elements do not have multi-line inside them, which makes the text become truncated.

Context menu is one of them, so I've made my own implementation of it using an AlertDialog.

However, I see the same problem on the actionBar sub menu, and I think the same problem appears when using the [**PopupMenu**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html) class :

(look at the third item in the sub menu)

[image]

### The question

Is there an easy way to overcome this issue, or should I make my own implementation of it, as I've done for the context menu?

Is there also a way to overcome this issue for PopupMenu?

Would adding a style for popupMenu (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20730678/878126)) help?

How do I make the textViews that are used on those UI components have multi-line in them?

Comment: You can change the style of this menu so you can change the size of the text with `textSize` option. So, I think that if you reduce the text size it won't truncate.

Comment: @Akagami I don't want to reduce the size of the text. I just want to make it multi-line as needed.

Comment: @android_developer I think you have to create a custom layout for that. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868774/android-action-bar-custom-dropdown-view-on-item-click

Comment: @Akagami Maybe I could use the PopupMenu class, and duplicate everything from the actionBar sub menu, yet use multi-line instead? is it possible? I can't find out how to achieve it though... Maybe I should use PopupWindow instead?

Comment: @android_developer I would go for the custom layout but I posted an answer for a PopupWindow. Check it out if you decide to use one!

Answer (score 0):

Creating a PopupWindow:

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterTypeSelection;
private void popupWindow(View v, Point p) {

    // int popupwindowWidth =
    // UnitConverterClass.convertDpToPx(180,getActivity());
    int popupwindowHeight = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.dashboard_profile_popup_window, null);

    // Creating the PopupWindow
    final PopupWindow pwindow = new PopupWindow(getActivity());
    pwindow.setContentView(layout);
    // pwindow.showAsDropDown(v);
    // pwindow.setWidth(popupwindowWidth);
    pwindow.setHeight(popupwindowHeight);
    pwindow.setFocusable(true);

    String[] types = {"hello", "hi"};

    adapterTypeSelection = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.<your layout for the popupwindow>,
            R.id.textView, types);

    ListView listview = (ListView) pwindow.getContentView().findViewById(
            R.id.listview_popwindow);

    listview.setAdapter(adapterTypeSelection);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            TextView temp = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(position)
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView);

            if (temp.getText()
                    .toString()
                    .equals("hello"))) {
                //hello
            } else {
                //hi
            }

            pwindow.dismiss();
        }
    });

    pwindow.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            //TODO dismiss settings
        }

    });

    pwindow.setWidth(<width>);
    pwindow.setBackgroundDrawable(<resource for background>);

    // int OFFSET_X = UnitConverterClass.convertDpToPx(180, getActivity());
    // int OFFSET_Y = UnitConverterClass.convertDpToPx(30, getActivity());
    // pwindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 
    //                                p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);
    pwindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x, p.y);
}
```

Then you create a OnClickListener for the button like this:

```
actionBarButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int[] location = new int[2];
            v.getLocationOnScreen(location);

            // Initialize the Point with x, and y positions
            Point point = new Point();
            point.x = location[0];
            point.y = location[1];

            popupWindow(v, point);

        }

    }
);
```

Hope this helps if you really want to use a PopupWindow but I would still go for the custom layout on the menu.

Comment: ummm.... the content was correct, but the name wasn't. I've now deleted the post. here's the content: Interesting. Sadly I can't do it right now, as I have an army-draft (I'm from Israel), so I hope to remember to get back to this some time in the future. thank you.