# Creating custom actionbar popup menu using layout

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I'm trying to create a custom popup/drop down menu on Android where when I click the action button from action bar the list of overflow options will appear but in a different format (image on right instead of left, button, etc). I tried to find some question and the one close to this is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868774/android-action-bar-custom-dropdown-view-on-item-click/14929002#14929002) but the answer is incomplete and lacks the explanation. Now what I tried so far is to replicate it but removed the DropDown class but nothing happens as expected. I also tried some ways using the xml menu but its just giving me the same result of image on left and text on right. I think setActionView also doesn't work the way I expected it. Hope someone can help me on this.