# Implementing custom menu items like in feedly app

Tags: android, menu, customization, menuitem

i try to made something like this

[image]

but i dont know what element need to use? and how need this element.
maybe need to create layout for menu, or use popupWindows element.

Anybody can help?

Comment: Have a look at http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views.html

Comment: Creating a custom action provider???

Comment: That's one possibility, yes, and probably the easiest one, since everything else will require you to write everything from scratch

Comment: here you would find good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868774/android-action-bar-custom-dropdown-view-on-item-click

Comment: i cant find solutions for menu like this(

Comment: i need menu like table but i find solutions for customization menu in actions bar, like "search", create provider with checkbox, but i not find solutions for menu like on picture.